# SQL Query taking much longer to select than inserting into a temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that takes about 1.5 minutes to run if it runs as an insert into an empty temp table, but selecting the data doesn't complete even after 20 minutes. Why would a select take so much longer than an insert? Will SQL Server draw different plans based on that?

The estimated execution plans are the same for both, the actual execution plan is different than the estimated.

> Update: It seems that the INSERT version of the query is using
> parallelism, while the select version is not. My question still
> remains as to why that is?

Comment: to me, looks like a locking issue.  did you execute sp_who2 to make sure this isn't the case?

Comment: No, I will try. Why would the select cause a locking issue rather than an insert?

Comment: When you insert in a table the data does not have to be sent over the network to your client.

Comment: @Wouter yes but the time difference is much greater than it would take send the data over.

Comment: @MLeblanc it doesn't seem like a locking issue

Comment: then, how much row do you have into the temp table? if you have lot a row (over 1 million) execute in SSMS, it's normal to take a lot of time, SSMS has issues with the grid.  The problem it's not the query, but the way SSMS print the result in the grid.

Comment: What are the datatypes and there precision of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Once a single query plan reaches a certain level of complexity, I often have a better experience sequencing a collection of smaller queries together than one really big nasty query.  This enables the query optimizer to evaluate a smaller request.

Locking duration in a highly transnational database can also be a significant contributing factor.

It sounds like you're on to something with the parallelism.  There are several operators within SQL that will prevent parallelism.